# A good way to return a vector using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I read theory about pointers in C, but I only have confusion in mind.

Imagine that I call a method which has to return me an array of floats using pointers (not return statement).

First point: must the head of my method be this way: `myMet([somearguments], float* myvector)`?

Second point: Is it recommended to create another array in my method's body, fill it and then do

`*myvector = thatarray` ?

I'm so sorry to ask such a basic question, but pointers in C seem so hostile to me

Comment: "*I only have confusion in mind.*" \*giggles\* I would suggest to look for a different wording ;)

Comment: As for the question, it might *look* basic, but requires a lot of explanations ... it's actually quite broad.

Comment: hahaha @FelixPalmen

Comment: `*myvector = thatarray` you cannot copy an array like that.

Comment: Note that is is not possible to return an array (e.g., of `float`s), though you can wrap an array in a `struct` and return it, but this would probably not be the right solution, even without the pointer restriction.

Comment: I suggest your function should return the number of elements *used* in the array.

Comment: There are just too many possibilities to give you an answer. I would need some more context or an example of what you want.

Comment: I think start your study from something easier. Try to understand what the pointer is, how the pointer arithmetic works, then scopes of the variables. And buy a good C textbook

Comment: C does not support _methods_. Nor does it have a vector type. And such basic (indeed!) questions will be answered by reading a good C book.

Comment: *"Confusion! Will be my epitaph!"*

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you do not want to "hardcode" the size of the array in one way or another. So you probably already had an idea along those lines:

(beware, **broken code follows**)

```
float *foo(void)
{
    float x[] = { 0, 1.3, 27.4 };
    return x;
}
```

This has multiple problems, the first one is **it doesn't work at all**: You return a pointer to a local variable, and a local variable has *automatic storage duration*, so it doesn't exist any more once the scope is left. From this function, you get a pointer that doesn't point at any valid location.

---

How to do it correctly, there are multiple possibilities. The idiomatic C solution is that your **calling** code provides the actual array, this is feasible in all cases where you can have good assumptions about the size needed:

```
size_t foo(float *arr, size_t size)
{
    float x[] = { 0, 1.3, 27.4, -1.5, 23 };
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size && i < 5; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = x[i];
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    float x[20];

    // would return 5:
    size_t elements = foo(x, 20);
}
```

If this is **not** feasible, you have to use `malloc()` in your function. You can either still return the size and e.g. modify a provided pointer with a signature like this:

```
size_t foo(float **arr)
{
    size_t elements = 5;
    *arr = malloc( elements * sizeof(**arr) );
    // check *arr for NULL, if ok fill it
}

int main(void)
{
    float *x;
    size_t elements = foo(&x);
    // process results
    free(x);
}
```

Or, what I personally like better, you could define a `struct` that contains the size and return this:

```
struct floats
{
    size_t n;
    float vals[];
}

struct floats *foo(void)
{
    size_t elements = 5;
    struct floats *x = malloc(sizeof(*x) + elements * sizeof(float));
    // check for NULL, handle error ...

    x->n = elements;
    // fill elements in x->vals ...

    return x;
}
```

Note that although this is a `struct`, you can't just return the struct itself. Because of the flexible array member, it's type is *incomplete* (so at compile time, the size is unknown), therefore you can only return a pointer to it. But if you could know the size in advance, you should go for my first alternative anyways (having the caller provide the array).

---

As a general hint not related to your question: Using `float` is **very very rarely** a good idea. In almost every case, you want to use `double` instead.

Comment: You last example is correct because you return a pointer to an allocated *dynamic* struct. But you should warn that such an *incomplete* type cannot be returned by value.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I implicitly assumed the "vector" to be large enough that returning it by value wouldn't be considered at all ;) But I'll try to find a good wording for your suggestion.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: You cannot return an array by value anyway, so nothing lost. A bit more of a problem might be you cannot define a `struct` with FAM. But that is often not a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to understand the double pointers.

If you know how many floats will be returned from the function

```
/*
    we know foo always returns N values
*/
void foo(float *ret, int N)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      ret[i] = ((float)i)/N;
}

if we don't know

/*
    return a list of numbers of random length
*/
void foo(float **ret, int *Nret)
{
   int N = rand() % 100;
   float *answer = malloc(N * sizeof(float));
   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     answer[i] = ((float)i)/N;
   *ret = answer;
   *Nret = N;
}
```

Comment: it less expensive just to return N instead of passing the pointer and assigning it without the reason.

Comment: True yes. But some coding standards reserve returns for errors, or you might return more than one array. Sadly the more realistic examples are also longer.